# Discrete metric, singleton open or closed set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

#### Could someone check the following, is my reasoning correct?

*EDIT: the following contains errors: see comments*

> Let $$d_\text{disc}(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x\not = y\\ 0 & \text{if } x=y\end{cases}$$

Consider a metric space $(M,d_\text{disc})$ and consider $\{ x\} \subset M$. Then:

- $\{x\}$ is closed, since $x$ is not an interior point of $\{ x\}$. It is impossible to find a $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq \{x\}$,
- $B(x,1)$ is open by definition.

Since in $(M,d_\text{disc})$ the sets $\{ x\}$ and $B(x,1)$ are equal, $\{x\}$ is both open and closed.

Since the union of open sets is open, and the union of closed sets is closed:

- $(\forall U \subseteq M)(U$ is open )
- $(\forall U \subseteq M)(U$ is closed )

#### Supplementary small questions:

Does this imply that the words `open' and 'closed' are not complete?

If I want to be formal, should I always give the used metric? Writing $d_\text{disc}$-open instead of open?

Comment: It's not impossible to find $r > 0$ such that $B(x, r) \subseteq \{ x \}$.  If $r = \frac{1}{2}$, then $B(x, \frac{1}{2})$ is by definition the points in $M$ that are less than $\frac{1}{2}$ distance from $x$.  But there is only one point satisfying this: $x$.  So $B(x, \frac{1}{2}) = \{ x \}$.  So $x$ is an interior point of $\{x \}$ (since $\{x \}$ is open and thus its interior equals itself).

Comment: The union of closed sets is not necessarily closed. It is true however that every set $U$ here is closed. This because its complement is open. You are dealing here with the so-called discrete topology. Every subset of $M$ is open and as a consequence of that every subset of $M$ is closed.

Comment: In the discrete metric, _any_ subset is both open and closed at the same time (they're "clopen"). I don't know what you mean by "complete", but no, "open" and "closed" are not opposite in meaning, and they are not disjoint. The only thing we can say in general about openness versus closedness is that if one set is open, then the complement is closed, and vice versa. Some sets are both. Some sets are neither (but not in this specific metric).

Comment: @Arthur Okay, seems my reasoning is not right then. So the correct way should be something like: $\{x\} = B(x,1)$ is open, so each $U\subseteq M$ will be open (as a union of open singletons). Then each complement of $U$ is closed, but this complement is also an union of open singletons which makes it open.

Comment: Yes. Since every subset is open (being a union of open balls), and every subset is the complement of _some_ $U$, we have that every subset is closed as well. But remember for next time: Infinite unions of closed sets are not generally closed, and infinite intersections of open sets are not generally open.

Comment: @drhab "The union of closed sets is not necessarily closed". I thought it was? Do you mean that there are some 'exotic' metrics where my intuition would fail? Since every subset of $M$ is both closed and open the statement holds for the discrete metric?

Comment: @dietervdf "...each complement of $U$..." It has only *one* complement. And it was allready observed that each subset of $M$ is open. An apart reasoning for this complement to be open is redundant.

Comment: Take e.g. the union of all closed balls with radius $r<1$ in $\mathbb R$ equipped with its usual metric. This is the open ball with radius $1$. It is not closed. Not quite exotic.

Comment: The finite union of closed sets is closed.  But the infinite union of closed sets not nescessarily so.  No need for exotic metrics.  On the "usual" metric $\cup_{i \in \mathbb N} [1/n, 1- 1/n] = (0,1)$ which is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ is the discrete metric on any set $X$, then as the union of any open sets in a metric space is open and a set in a metric space is closed if and only if the complement is open, we have: Let $A \subset X$, then $A = \bigcup_{x \in A} B_{d}(x, \frac{1}{2}) = \bigcup_{x \in A} \{x\}$. As $A$ is a union of open sets, $A$ is open for each $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$.\
It then follows that each set is closed as well.

Answer (score 1):

"{x} is closed, since x is not an interior point of {x}. It is impossible to find a r>0 such that B(x,r)⊆{x},"

1)  Closed does *NOT* mean "not open".  So proving {x} is not open, do *not* mean {x} is closed.

2)The *EXACT OPPOSITE*!!!!!

$x$ !!!!!**IS**!!!! an interior point of $\{x\}$!  If $r = 1$ then $B(x,1) = \{y| d(x,y) < 1\} = \{y|d(x,y) = 0\} = \{x\}\subset \{x\}$.  So $\{x\}$ is open.

I don't know what you mean but "open" and "closed" are "not complete".

Anyway, it's  very well known that in the discrete metric space *all* sets are *both* open and closed.

If $S$ is a non-empty set, and $x \in S$. Then $\{y|d(y,x) < 1\} = \{x\} \subset S$ so $x$ is an interior point and all points are interior points in $S$ so S is open.  (The empty set is always vacuously open.).

We use the fact that a set is closed if and only if its complement is open.  So as the complement of all Sets are open (because all sets are open) all sets are closed.

Comment: Argh!  I posted to *another* zombie post!!! Why or why do these things keep popping up!!!!!!